# How to iterate through divs to scrape the text from a website using NodeJS and Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to scrape the text from 5 different divs of a website, but the problem is that I cannot make use of the class name nor of the ID. I observed that what those divs have in common, is that the text of those 5 different divs are encapsulated in a span attribute, and that attribute is only used where I need to scrape the text from. This is my code so far, but I am stuck at the beginning of the scraping:

```
const fs = require("fs/promises"); 
const express = require ("express"); 
const cors = require("cors");
const _ = require("lodash"); //pick a random item from an array
const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid"); //object destructuring; uuid to generate unique id
const { sample } = require("lodash");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

async function performScraping(){

const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); //support json
app.use(express.cors());

//Downloading the target web page
//by performing an HTTP GET request in Axios
const axiosResponse = await axios.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://wsa-test.vercel.app/",
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
});

//parsing the HTML source of the target web page with Cheerio
const $ = cheerio.load(axiosResponse.data);

//initializing the data structures
//that will contain the scraped data

//scraping
const descriptions = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(desc of descriptions){
    
}


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("API Server is running..."));
}
```

So, tldr, what I really want to to is to extract the title of the article and the short description of it, using Cheerio, both being in a span attribute. I am also attaching an image of the HTML and the span in cause: [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1bvW.png)

I tried to play with different DOM elements, but none worked.

*UPDATE*: Regarding my problem with the IDs and class names constraint, I was thinking of this solution, as a rule came to my mind. Any idea if it's any good?

```
const links = $('a');

for(let i = 1; i < links.length; i += 2){
    const title = $(links[i]).text().trim();
    const shortDescription = $(links[i]).nextAll('div').eq(-2).text().trim();

    if(title && shortDescription){
        const scrapedData = {
            title: title,
            short_description: shortDescription
        }
        scraped.push(scrapedData);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `document.querySelector()` supposed to do in Node (presumably without JSDOM)? You create a cheerio object `$` but never use it. Can you show the exact output you expect, as text? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase. I want to extract the title and the description of every article of that website. It should look like this, in JSON format: [
{
"title": "The Joys of Gardening",
"short_description": "Explore the enriching world of gardening and
discover its positive impact on mood and well-being."
},
{
"title": "The Challenges of Urban Living",
"short_description": "A candid look at the challenges of urban
living, with insights into coping strategies."
},
...
] In the HTML, the elements have randomly generated class names, so I cannot use them.

Comment: You can have some idea from herehttps://github.com/anik587/otomoto-scraper

Comment: I discovered a rule in the HTML, that bein that the title of every article is between the <a> and </a> tags, and the description text is the second to last div in every "main" div of the blogs from the website.

Comment: Thanks, I'd [edit] that expected output into your question, but it's basically the same as I guessed in my answer. Please read my comment there--I think there's some ongoing confusion between scraping the data, and even just getting a document that has the data in it. The HTML response you have here doesn't have any of your data in it. It's loaded after the page loads by a JS script. Cheerio and a single axios request can't get it regardless of what selectors or strategies you use.

Comment: Once you get back to the selector issue, if you have 5 sites, please share them all so it can be determined how best to scrape them.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get that data with a direct request to the static HTML, because the data you want is loaded asynchronously by JS. Always check `view-source:` in the browser or print the HTML axios gives you to ensure the data's there. Don't trust the dev tools, which shows elements loaded by JS after the page load.

You could use a browser automation solution like Puppeteer to extract the data you want:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.2.1

const url = "https://wsa-test.vercel.app/";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const sel = '[class^="group"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  const data = await page.$$eval(sel, els => 
    els.map(e => ({
      name: e.querySelector("div").textContent,
      desc: e.querySelector("div:nth-child(2)").textContent
    }))
  );
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

---

If you're unable to use browser automation, the data is in https://wsa-test.vercel.app/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-f116d58692ffa69b.js, but that's a generated build file with a dynamic hash, so you'd have to make two requests. First, request the index HTML, then extract this script tag's source with Cheerio:

```html
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-f116d58692ffa69b.js" defer=""></script>
```

After you have the script source URL, you can request the JS file in a second request and parse the data structure starting with `h=[{id:1,title:"The Joys of Gardening" ...` out of the response text with regex. Finally, you'd process the data structure to pull out only the information you need.

This is probably too much work and carries its own reliability risks (script URLs and object structures can change), so I don't recommend it unless speed is absolutely critical or you're in an environment where Puppeteer is too heavy to run.

Here's a proof of concept of what this might look like:

```js
const axios = require("axios"); // ^1.4.0
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12
const JSON5 = require("json5"); // ^2.2.3

const url = "https://wsa-test.vercel.app";

axios.get(url)
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const scriptSrc = $(
      [...$("script")].find(e =>
        $(e)
          .attr("src")
          .includes("/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-")
      )
    ).attr("src");
    return axios.get(url + scriptSrc);
  })
  .then(({data: text}) => {
    const h = JSON5.parse(text.match(/h=(\[\{id:.*}]);/)[1]);
    const data = h.map(({title, description}) => ({
      title,
      description,
    }));
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

`eval` is also possible instead of JSON5 for parsing the JS object (not JSON!) string, but it's incredibly risky running untrusted JS, so I don't recommend this in production:

```js
eval(text.match(/h=\[\{id:.*?}];/)[0]); // danger! unsafe eval!
const data = h.map(({title, description}) => ({
// ...
```

Hopefully this exercise helps motivate Puppeteer as the first option.

Comment: This would be too complicated for my task, it has to be way easier than that. My only problem is that I cannot make use of neither the class name nor the IDs, as they are randomly generated.

Comment: The `group-` prefix should be stable. Only the numbers after `group-` are random. If you can't rely on that, you can use `span` or whatever selector you want--it's beside the point. The main point is even just getting the data at all, which you'll need one of the two methods I outlined to do. Your current approach won't give you the HTML with any usable data regardless of which selectors you use.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can do:

```
$('a[href*="/blog/"]').get().map(a => {
  return {
    title: $(a).text(),
    description: $(a).closest('div').next().text()
  }
})
```

Comment: This gives me an empty array, because the data isn't available statically on the base page OP is requesting. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77276375/6243352). Maybe I'm missing something--can you add the request that you're using here so the code is fully runnable and I can understand the approach here? Thanks!

Comment: @ggorlen I'm just going by the html, if that html isn't there then yes they have to switch to puppeteer