# How to use Cheerio to get JSON data within a script tag

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape metadata from a bunch of websites. For most, using Cheerio to get things like `$('meta[property="article:published_time"]').attr('content')` works fine. However, for others this meta data property is not explicitly defined but the data is present in some form in the HTML.

For example, if I scrape [this page](https://news.yahoo.com/venezuela-deploys-soldiers-face-guyana-175722970.html), there is no `published_time` metadata property, but this text is present in the file ...

```
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"NewsArticle","mainEntityOfPage":"https://news.yahoo.com/venezuela-deploys-soldiers-face-guyana-175722970.html","headline":"Venezuela Deploys Troops to East Caribbean Coast, Citing Guyana Threat","datePublished":"2023-12-28T19:53:10.000Z","dateModified":"2023-12-28T19:53:10.000Z","keywords":["Nicolas Maduro","Venezuela","Bloomberg","Guyana","Essequibo","Exxon Mobil Corp"],"description":"(Bloomberg) -- Venezuela has decided to deploy more than 5,000 soldiers on its eastern Caribbean coast after neighboring Guyana received a warship from the...","publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Yahoo News","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_news_en-US_h_p_news_2.png","width":310,"height":50},"url":"https://news.yahoo.com/"},"author":{"@type":"Person","name":"Andreina Itriago Acosta","url":"","jobTitle":""},"creator":{"@type":"Person","name":"Andreina Itriago Acosta","url":"","jobTitle":""},"provider":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Bloomberg","url":"https://www.bloomberg.com/","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","width":339,"height":100,"url":"https://s.yimg.com/cv/apiv2/hlogos/bloomberg_Light.png"}},"image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/hs3Vjof2BqloeagLdsvfDw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTEyMDA7aD0xMjAy/https://media.zenfs.com/en/bloomberg_politics_602/2db14d66c52bec70cb0ec6d0553968c6","width":1200,"height":1202},"thumbnailUrl":"https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/hs3Vjof2BqloeagLdsvfDw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTEyMDA7aD0xMjAy/https://media.zenfs.com/en/bloomberg_politics_602/2db14d66c52bec70cb0ec6d0553968c6"}
```

There is a `"datePublished"` field in this object. How do I get this property with Cheerio?

Comment: I notice you have many unanswered questions. To improve visibility, consider adding 4-5 tags including [tag:javascript] to your questions. [tag:cheerio] is an extremely small tag, and adding that alone will only expose it to a few people at the very most, unless you get really lucky and it's a commonly-searched topic with a high ranking on google. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you want is in JSON format inside a `<script>` tag. To find the data, I would select all `<script>` tags, then loop over them to find one with the `'"datePublished":'` substring, extract the text, run it through `JSON.parse()` and finally access the `.datePublished` property:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const el = [...$("script")].find(e =>
      $(e).text().includes('"datePublished":')
    );
    const meta = JSON.parse($(el).text()); // => 2023-12-28T19:53:10.000Z
    console.log(meta.datePublished);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66878732/6243352) for a general tutorial on this particular technique. It's in Python, but the same concepts apply in Node. Sometimes the JSON within the `<script>` is a JS object, or assigned to a variable, which makes the parsing a bit trickier than the straightforward scenario here, typically requiring a bit of regex or [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) to parse. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77276375/6243352) for a more complex example of parsing data from a `<script>` tag using Cheerio.